# Find rows using foreign key in TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an OneToMany relation from `User` to `Message`.

When I insert register a user with a message, it adds the user to the `User` table, and the message to the `Message` table with a `userId` pointing to the user's id.

This is done automatically using the following setup.

`User` entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() 
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @JoinTable()
  @OneToMany((type) => Message, (message) => message.user, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  messages: Message[];
}
```

`Message` entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Message {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  text: string;
  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.messages, { eager: true })
  user: User[];
}
```

If I want to find all messages from a user via `userId` with:

```
const existing_msgs = await this.messageRepository.find({
    where: { userId: user.id },
});
```

It tells me that it cannot find the `userId` column, which is understandable as I did not specifically include `userId` to the `Message` entity.

But how would we query it in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentionned in [This post](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4396#issuecomment-561785249), you have to add the decorator @JoinColumn after your manytoone. This will join the column and you will be able to perform the query you want with :

```
const existing_msgs = await this.messageRepository.find({
    where: { user: { id: user.id }},
});
```

Note that this will work only on primary column like id.

And your message table will be :

```
@Entity()
export class Message {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  text: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.messages, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn() // <-- Add this
  user: User[];
}
```

Comment: good but you missed ':' at   -->   where: { user : { id: user.id} }

Comment: you're right, just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the following querybuilder.

```
        const msg_arr = await this.userRepository
          .createQueryBuilder('user')
          .leftJoinAndSelect('user.messages', 'messages')
          .where('user.id = :userId', { userId: user.id })
          .andWhere('messages.text LIKE :text', { text: message })
          .select('messages.text')
          .execute();
```